# Is a Secure Oauth2 Web App Flow with FE and BE the right approach?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, okta

We have a Web Application that mints an internal JWT used for authentication along with a secure cookie. As the organization has been moving to Okta there is an ask to integrate that login flow into our app.

Our current workflow:

- We have a Spring Boot (version 2.5.x) login endpoint which receives a userId and Password.
- The login is validated and then an internal jwt is created with the userId, assigned role and some other metadata.
- The FE client receives that jwt and sends it for every authenticated request.

It poses a lot of challenges. After some analysis, I think I see how I want to approach it:

- The Okta application is configured for "Grant Type". redirect and logout callbacks point to the FE client URL
- The FE client makes the call to the Okta server to get the **authorizationCode**
- The FE client makes a call to the BE server to do an `/sso-login`, passing in the **authorizationCode** as a parameter
- the BE calls the okta `{okta-server}/token` endpoint to get the okta bearer token and parse the results to get `userName`
- the internal JWT is minted based on the userName and associated roles and sent back to the FE along with a secure cookie

Does this flow make sense? Is it safe? Most literature and examples I see tend to involve SPA or integrate everything in the BE.

Because of the opaqueness of the Spring oauth2 integration I am favoring avoiding that for now and manually constructing my POST call to the `/token` endpoint.

Comment: The Spring OAuth2 implementations are not opaque at all. Maybe are you just lacking [some OAuth2 background](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#OAuth2_essentials)?

Comment: `the internal JWT is minted` - minted how? what does 'minted' mean? what is the point of Okta giving you an auth code if you're presumably creating your own JWT? why don't you use the Okta one?

Comment: The point is to support sso as all our other apps do. Using the okta one would involve a massive refactor so we are looking at this as the first step of an iterative process

Comment: Just pass the access token from FE to BE and have the BE validate the Okta token? Sorry, the question is not clear on what the exact question is, what you have currently, where the aim is to be and what the 'first step' is.

Comment: Not the access token. FE would obtain the authorization code and pass that to the BE which would get the token. This is from the "authorization by grant type" workflow. The Code is then used to get the jwt token. I will edit the question to be more clear on what we currently have.

Comment: Another Q: why can't you make your backend just accept your Okta token (too)?

Comment: I think we can... it would happen in Phase II. If easier than I realize then perhaps sooner. There is some information we currently embed in our internal token that we would need in the Okta one or accessible elsewhere

Comment: But you could then augment the token based on the information in the Okta token, no? If not, then what you have is a variation of the token mediating backend and is 'secure' i.e. there's no glaring security issues here.

Comment: I think it took a while for my inflexible brain to understand the logic of what you are saying. I do agree now: the FE should pass the token to the BE. The BE should ensure the token is valid and use it to create the InternalToken.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend minting your own JWT. I would recommend packaging your frontend and backend together and doing all your authentication on the backend. Especially if your apps live on the same host. If they can't live on the same host, do the authentication in your frontend and pass an access token to the backend.

These two tutorials show how to package the apps together while maintaining the development workflow of working on them separately.

- [Use React and Spring Boot to Build a Simple CRUD App](https://auth0.com/blog/simple-crud-react-and-spring-boot/)
- [Build a Beautiful CRUD App with Spring Boot and Angular](https://auth0.com/blog/spring-boot-angular-crud/)

This tutorial shows how to do all the authentication on the frontend:

- [Build a Simple CRUD App with Spring Boot and Vue.js](https://auth0.com/blog/build-crud-spring-and-vue/)

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: Just to clarify- we are already creating a JWT with our internal permissions. The goal is here is to begin an iterative process to transition to SSO with OAuth2. The end goal is managing users and permissions completely in Okta. I think passing the accessToken from FE to BE makes sense, but is the objection to the "split" workflow one of security or just best practices?

Comment: If you own the backend, it's a best security practice to do the authentication there. If you have a SPA and don't control the backend, you'll be forced to authenticate on the frontend. Some folks like to deploy to different hosts for the frontend and backed too, which requires the split architecture.

Comment: Thanks Matt- glad to have some input from the expert!

Comment: I don't see the point in using `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` in the first two tutorials: only session security is used by the frontends.

Comment: The pattern used in the last tutorial is not following latest [Spring Security team recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390). Even if you don't have the hand on the OAuth2 resource servers, the OAuth2 clients should be confidentials, which requires it to run on your servers. `spring-cloud-gateway` can be used for that purpose when configured with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`, `oauth2Login` and `TokenRelay=` filter.

Comment: @MattRaible What is the advantage of packaging the front-end and back-end applications together? What kind of security benefits does it provide?
Either way, isn't the front-end application running in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

According to [latest recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), OAuth2 clients (applications to which tokens are delivered and which store those tokens) should be "confidential" (secured with some sort of secret). This requires it to run on a server you trust (neither Javascript based apps in a browser nor mobile apps can keep a secret).

This means that, to follow OAuth2 best practices, **your React app should not be an OAuth2 client** nor have access to tokens. Its requests to the backend should be authorized with session cookies (which requires protection against CSRF attacks).

The pattern I use in [this app](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) (with Angular) or [this other one](https://github.com/ch4mpy/tahiti-numerique/blob/master/web-front-office) (with React but with a French README), is to set a `spring-cloud-gateway` instance as BFF in charge of requests routing and authorization. When user authentication is required:

- the Javascript based app exits by setting the window location to an URI on the gateway to initiate `authorization_code` flow
- the gateway redirects to the authorization server (Okta in your case)
- after the user authenticated, the authorization server redirects back to the gateway with authorization-code
- the gateway exchanges the authorization-code for tokens and store it in session
- the gateway redirects back to the React app

With this pattern, requests are protected with:

- sessions (and CSRF, but not tokens) between the front-end (React, Angular, Vue, etc.) and the gateway
- tokens (not sessions nor CSRF) between the gateway and downstream REST APIs (which should be configured as stateless resource servers).

If you inspect about any serious OAuth2 app with your browser debugging tools (Gmail, Facebook, LinkedIn, etc.), you'll find session cookies but no `Authorization` header with a Bearer token. You won't even find an OAuth2 token anywhere in your browser. The reason is that they apply this pattern...